# Unable to load data with emberJS

Tags: ember.js

I have the following Ember app. But when I go to the `/products` route I've got the following error: `Error while loading route: TypeError {}`

```
var App = Ember.Application.create();
App.Router.map(function() {
  this.route('products');
});

DS.Store.extend({
  revision: 11,
  adapter: DS.RESTAdapter.create()
});

var Product = DS.Model.extend({});

var ProductsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return App.Product.find();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your code wont run because your model and route does not exist is scope of the `App`. It should look like this:

```
var App = Ember.Application.create();
App.Router.map(function() {
    this.route('products');
});

DS.Store.extend({
    revision: 11,
    adapter: DS.RESTAdapter.create()
});

App.Product = DS.Model.extend({});

App.ProductsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        return App.Product.find();
    }
});
```

Next, you may want to replace:

```
this.route('products');
```

with:

```
this.resource('products');
```

as you are using `RESTAdapter`.

Finally `DS.Model` should specify which fields it should user from JSON response:

```
App.Product = DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr('string')
});
```

Hope it will help.